# Setting ng-show value from controller but my code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

New to angular js. I read many solution regarding my code. The problem, I am facing is that, I have two tables. By default one table is hide and one one is visible. I want to show hidden table when I click on button and want to hide second table. When I click on button the ng-show value updated but table doesn't hide and required table doesn't show up. Thanks in advance for your help.

Code on page load : controller.js

```
var refresh = function(){
            /** Driver Profile Data */
            $scope.userProfile_show  = true;
            $scope.editUserProfile_show  = false;
            $http.get('/user/profile/?user_id='+$location.search()['driverID'], {headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ANmI3xaBz3MQMbrOs3XAtuAwEgZt1pbOhSMGfHHTxwhgyi4SJfmmOGcxN5bEwhFh26TyfTgKxhtHpX9rGPWHgtB7D3LBex5mDkxBL7LyhvQ2MjPNBkeNZyUBgBuhO1IK9n13YHdpfbnMdnep4PRnDHScMWmJi1kV0NxkgiIsEC3x0pHZxhhLvgEIEqF6qGVLPSXN010Em8rzXraPGV9NyG6t6a0zYYlDKONYvQ7FnwP1p67ViTu2wUgbilnwoymQ'}
            }).success(function (response) {
                $scope.userProfile = response.data;
            });

            });
        }

        refresh();
```

HTML Code:

```
<table class="table" id = "editUserProfile" ng-show = "{{editUserProfile_show}}">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Property</td>
                        <td>Value</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
<table>

<table class="table" id = "userProfile" ng-show= "{{userProfile_show}}">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="col-md-5">
                    <col class="col-md-7">
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User Profile</th>
                        <th style="text-align: -webkit-right"><button class="btn-primary btn" id = "editUserProfile_button" ng-click = "editUserProfile()">Edit User Profile</button></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
<table>
```

On page load both table are working properly, But when click on button "Edit User Profile" then values of ng-show are updated but table doesn't switch their visibility.

Controller code for editUserProfile()

```
$scope.editUserProfile = function(){
            $scope.editUserProfile_show  = true;
            $scope.userProfile_show  = false;
            $http.get('/user/profile/?user_id=559f6d43cd9e9cfd07422baa', {headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ANmI3xaBz3MQMbrOs3XAtuAwEgZt1pbOhSMGfHHTxwhgyi4SJfmmOGcxN5bEwhFh26TyfTgKxhtHpX9rGPWHgtB7D3LBex5mDkxBL7LyhvQ2MjPNBkeNZyUBgBuhO1IK9n13YHdpfbnMdnep4PRnDHScMWmJi1kV0NxkgiIsEC3x0pHZxhhLvgEIEqF6qGVLPSXN010Em8rzXraPGV9NyG6t6a0zYYlDKONYvQ7FnwP1p67ViTu2wUgbilnwoymQ'}
            }).success(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.userProfile = response.data;
            });
        };
```

HTML View after clicking function:

```
<table class="table ng-hide" id="editUserProfile" ng-show="true">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Property</td>
                        <td>Value</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
</table>

<table class="table" id="userProfile" ng-show="false">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="col-md-5">
                    <col class="col-md-7">
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User Profile</th>
                        <th style="text-align: -webkit-right"><button class="btn-primary btn" id="editUserProfile_button" ng-click="editUserProfile()">Edit User Profile</button></th>
                    </tr>
</table>
```

when I click button then ng-hide class is added to first table editUserprofile. When I remove ng-hide class then this table is visible but second table is still visible although it's ng-show is false. Expecting, issue is related to $scope.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need string interpolation i.e. `{{ }}` with [`ngShow`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directive, it expects a [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). If the [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) is `truthy` then the element is shown or hidden respectively.

If you pass any string value `"true"` or `"false"` it will evaluate to `truthy` thus element will always be shown.

*Use*

```
ng-show = "editUserProfile_show"
```

*instead of*

```
ng-show = "{{editUserProfile_show}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need one variable defined in the scope. In the html for both the table's use the same scope attribute but for one table map it to `ng-show` and for the other table map the same attribute to `ng-hide`. Now based on the scope attribute only one table will be displayed at any given time.

On the `ng-click` of the button, just change the `attribute` on the `scope`.

In the controller:
    $scope.onShowClickEvent = function(){
      $scope.editUserProfile=true;
    }

```
$scope.onHideClickEvent = function(){
  $scope.editUserProfile=false;
}
```

On the view:

```
<table class="table ..." id="editUserProfile" ng-show="editUserProfile">
 ....
</table>

<table class="table ..." id="userProfile" ng-show="editUserProfile">
 ....
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.editUserProfile = function(){
        $scope.editUserProfile_show  = true;
        $scope.userProfile_show  = false;
        $http.get('/user/profile/?user_id=559f6d43cd9e9cfd07422baa', {headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ANmI3xaBz3MQMbrOs3XAtuAwEgZt1pbOhSMGfHHTxwhgyi4SJfmmOGcxN5bEwhFh26TyfTgKxhtHpX9rGPWHgtB7D3LBex5mDkxBL7LyhvQ2MjPNBkeNZyUBgBuhO1IK9n13YHdpfbnMdnep4PRnDHScMWmJi1kV0NxkgiIsEC3x0pHZxhhLvgEIEqF6qGVLPSXN010Em8rzXraPGV9NyG6t6a0zYYlDKONYvQ7FnwP1p67ViTu2wUgbilnwoymQ'}
        }).success(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.userProfile = response.data;
            $scope.editUserProfile_show  = false;
            $scope.userProfile_show  = true;
        });
    };


 var refresh = function(){
        /** Driver Profile Data */
        $scope.userProfile_show  = true;
        $scope.editUserProfile_show  = false;
        $http.get('/user/profile/?user_id='+$location.search()['driverID'], {headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ANmI3xaBz3MQMbrOs3XAtuAwEgZt1pbOhSMGfHHTxwhgyi4SJfmmOGcxN5bEwhFh26TyfTgKxhtHpX9rGPWHgtB7D3LBex5mDkxBL7LyhvQ2MjPNBkeNZyUBgBuhO1IK9n13YHdpfbnMdnep4PRnDHScMWmJi1kV0NxkgiIsEC3x0pHZxhhLvgEIEqF6qGVLPSXN010Em8rzXraPGV9NyG6t6a0zYYlDKONYvQ7FnwP1p67ViTu2wUgbilnwoymQ'}
        }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.userProfile = response.data;
            $scope.userProfile_show  = false;
            $scope.editUserProfile_show  = true;
        });

        });
    }
```

**On Success You need to change the value of the Scope variable then only it will reflect**

**you need to change the value  $scope.userProfile_show & $scope.editUserProfile_show  on success as stated above.**